# How to get information from generator object

Tags: python, bots, discord

next() doesn't work as it throws this error

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ServerDisconnectedError()>
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError
```

I've never used generator objects along with async before so excuse my utter incompetence

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('retrieve_'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, next(client.get_message(message.channel,str(-2))))
```

Comment: Because it is not a generator, but a coroutine: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message

Comment: so how do I retrieve the message then?

Comment: `await` for the message

Comment: when I type in retrieve_ it returns this:
<generator object Client.get_message at 0x035E2FC0>

Comment: What do you intend `retreive_` to do?

Comment: when discord bot sees 'retrieve_' it's supposed to send the message before the 'retrieve_' one